# Amazon SES verifyEmailIdentity is not sending email

Tags: node.js, amazon-ses

I want to automate the process of authorize email addresses to send mails through the Amazon SES service in javascript/Node.JS.

We are already sending mails via Node and that is working fine, but I can't get this working.

What I so far:

```
function verifyEmail(email, callback){
    var sesService = new AWS.SES({
        accessKeyId: "mykey",
        secretAccessKey: 'myaccesskey',
        region: 'eu-west-1'
    });
    sesService.verifyEmailIdentity({EmailAddress: email}, function(err, data){
        console.log("verifyEmailIdentity", err, data);
        return callback(err, data);        
    })
}
```

In the log I get this:

verifyEmailIdentity null
Object {ResponseMetadata: Object}

The ResponseMetadata object contains RequestId: "some-string"

So, I didn't get back an error but I didn't also receive an e-mail to confirm this request.

The key have the AmazonSESFullAccess policy added, so there are sufficient permissions to complete this.

I guess I forgot something very simple, but bases on the docs from Amazon I can't find what. And there aren't many examples for javascript is this, so I can't compare my code with others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still no idea why this wasn't working but now it works.

We had already plans to create an custom verify template (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/custom-verification-emails.html) and I created an template while waiting on an answer using the CLI.

For using this template we must use an the sendCustomVerificationEmail() function from AWS. 
And guess what? With that function the mail is send, and I'm able to verify the requested email address!

The verifyMail function now looks like:

```
function verifyEmail(email, callback){
    sesService.sendCustomVerificationEmail({
        EmailAddress: email,
        TemplateName: 'MyTemplateName'
        },function(err, data){
            console.log("verifyEmailIdentity", err, data);
            return callback(err, data);        
    })
}
```